# why `make` implicit rule doesn't work "across folders"?

Tags: makefile

I have two parallel folder hierarchies, and I'm trying to make `*.ttl` from `*.jsonld`

```
  JSON/*.jsonld
    AssociationEvent/*.jsonld
  Turtle/*.ttl
    AssociationEvent/*.ttl
```

`Turtle/Makefile` is like this:

```
JSONLD = $(wildcard ../JSON/*/*.jsonld) $(wildcard ../JSON/*.jsonld)
TTL    = $(JSONLD:../JSON/%.jsonld=%.ttl)

all: $(TTL)  $(warning JSONLD=$(JSONLD)) $(warning TTL=$(TTL))

%.ttl: ../JSON/%.jsonld
    jsonld format -q $^ | cat prefixes.ttl - | riot -syntax ttl -formatted ttl > $@
```

The `$(warning)` print what is expected, but then an error:

```
make
Makefile:4: JSONLD=../JSON/AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.jsonld ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
Makefile:4: TTL=AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.ttl Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.ttl
make: *** No rule to make target 'AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.ttl', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

The ttl in the current folder (eg `Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.ttl`) are made as expected, but for the ttl in subfolders (eg `AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.ttl`), make says it doesn't know how to make them. Printing debug info shows this (amongst many other things):

```
make -p
Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.ttl: ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema'
#  Last modified 2021-03-23 15:42:42.2814072
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.ttl
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema
# automatic
# + := ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
# automatic
# ^ := ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
# automatic
# ? := ../JSON/Example_9.8.1-MasterData-complying-with-schema.jsonld
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/13=8%
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 7):
        jsonld format -q $^ | cat prefixes.ttl - | riot -syntax ttl -formatted ttl > $@

# Not a target:
AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.ttl:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  File does not exist.
#  File has not been updated.
```

So it seems to me the implicit rule doesn't fire for filenames across folders. But the wildcard `%` in the implicit rule should match `/` like any other char??

```
%.ttl: ../JSON/%.jsonld
```

@MadScientist Sorry, your suggestion doesn't work:

```
JSONLD = $(wildcard ../JSON/*.jsonld) $(wildcard ../JSON/*/*.jsonld)
TTL    = $(JSONLD:../JSON/%.jsonld=./%.ttl)

all: $(TTL)

$(warning $(TTL))./%.ttl: ../JSON/%.jsonld
    jsonld format -q $^ | cat prefixes.ttl - | riot -syntax ttl -formatted ttl > $@
```

produces

```
./AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-a.ttl ./AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-c.ttl ...
make: *** No rule to make target 'AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-a.ttl', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I've read https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch12.html but couldn't debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match)

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule’s prerequisite patterns and the file name. The directories are ignored only for the purpose of finding an implicit rule to use, not in the application of that rule. Thus, ‘e%t’ matches the file name src/eat, with ‘src/a’ as the stem. When prerequisites are turned into file names, the directories from the stem are added at the front, while the rest of the stem is substituted for the ‘%’. The stem ‘src/a’ with a prerequisite pattern ‘c%r’ gives the file name src/car.

In this case, Make wants to build `AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g.ttl`, it sees the target pattern `%.ttl`, matches that rule with stem `AssociationEvent/AssociationEvent-g`, but then looks at the prerequisite pattern `../JSON/%.jsonld` and (here's where things go wrong) derives the prerequisite `AssociationEvent/../JSON/AssociationEvent-g.jsonld`. And there's no such file, so Make rejects this rule.

So much for the *explanation.* The least hideous *solution* I can think of at the moment involves dropping pattern rules in favor of generated rules:

```
define template
$(1).ttl: ../JSON/$(1).jsonld
    jsonld format -q $$^ ... > $$@
endef

$(foreach X,$(patsubst ../JSON/%.jsonld,%,$(JSONLD)),$(eval $(call template,$(X))))
```

Comment: You must be some sort of Dark Magic wizard!

Comment: Why not just make sure that the target pattern _does_ have a slash, so that it doesn't use the above special rule?  Does it work to change the target pattern to `./%.ttl`?  You may need to change the `TTL` variable as well.

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry, your suggestion doesn't work. See edited question

Comment: @MadScientist: That's a great idea and I wish I'd thought of it. But (the manual notwithstanding) the special rule seems to apply to `./%.ttl` as well.

Comment: Yeah... make tries to gracefully handle situations where you list `./foo` as a target but you have rules for `foo` and vice versa... that could be getting in the way here.  You could use `$(CURDIR)/` instead of `./` and see if that worked, but it gets more and more gross.